# Get nested fields from Kafka message using Apache Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I'm trying to create a source table using Apache Flink 1.11 where I can get access to nested properties in a JSON message.  I can pluck values off root properties but I'm unsure how to access nested objects.

The [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/formats/json.html#data-type-mapping) suggests that it should be a `MAP` type but when I set that, I get the following error

```
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlIdentifier: MAP
```

Here is my SQL

```sql
        CREATE TABLE input(
            id VARCHAR,
            title VARCHAR,
            properties MAP
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka-0.11',
            'topic' = 'my-topic',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
            'properties.group.id' = 'python-test',
            'format' = 'json'
        )
```

And my JSON looks something like this:

```json
{
  "id": "message-1",
  "title": "Some Title",
  "properties": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ROW` to extract nested fields in your JSON messages. Your DDL statement would look something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE input(
             id VARCHAR,
             title VARCHAR,
             properties ROW(`foo` VARCHAR)
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka-0.11',
            'topic' = 'my-topic',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
            'properties.group.id' = 'python-test',
            'format' = 'json'
        );
```

Comment: Excellent, this works!  How about deeply nested JSON, seems like this could get unwieldy?  Is there any better approaches for dealing with JSON data using PyFlink and SQL?

Comment: There isn't a better way to do this for now, AFAIK. There is a plan to support SQL JSON functions in Flink SQL soon, though: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=141724550 This should make things considerably easier!

Answer (score 7):

**[2022 Update]**

In release Apache Flink 1.13 there is no system built-in JSON functions.
They are introduced in 1.14 version. Check [this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/)

If you are using version <1.14, then see below solution.

**How can I create table with nested JSON input ?**

JSON input example:

```json
{
    "id": "message-1",
    "title": "Some Title",
    "properties": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "nested_foo":{
            "prop1" : "value1",
            "prop2" : "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

create statement

```sql
CREATE TABLE input(
                id VARCHAR,
                title VARCHAR,
                properties ROW(`foo` VARCHAR, `nested_foo` ROW(`prop1` VARCHAR, `prop2` VARCHAR))
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka-0.11',
            'topic' = 'my-topic',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
            'properties.group.id' = 'python-test',
            'format' = 'json'
        );
```

**How can I select nested columns?**

```
SELECT properties.foo, properties.nested_foo.prop1 FROM input;
```

Note that if you output the results with

```
SELECT properties FROM input
```

You see the results in row format. The content of the column `properties` will be

```
+I[bar, +I[prop1,prop2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try

```
CREATE TABLE input(
            id VARCHAR,
            title VARCHAR,
            properties MAP<STRING, STRING>
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka-0.11',
            'topic' = 'my-topic',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
            'properties.group.id' = 'python-test',
            'format' = 'json'
        )
```

The only difference is: `MAP<STRING, STRING>` vs `MAP`

Answer (score 1):

If use the `format=raw`, you can use the `JSON_VALUE` function to extract the field of interest from `payload`: Here is the code below:

```
 CREATE TABLE input(
        payload STRING,
        foo AS JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.properties.foo' RETURNING STRING),
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',        
  'format' = 'raw'
)
```